# How do I punctuate "according to" in a sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Here is the sentence I have trouble with:

> Please be informed, according to the local team, the part was delivered yesterday.

I have a friend saying that I should not separate the according to phrase by any commas, and that I should use *that* after *informed*.

What is right?

Comment: To me "Please be informed that according to the local team the part was delivered yesterday." sounds better.

Comment: Why does it sound better with "that" and why wouldn't you use any punctuation?

Comment: I'm a non-native so I may be wrong but I've met different sentences of the kind and they had no commas.

Answer (score 3):

Your punctuation is fine. You have a parenthetical (non-restrictive) clause that should be set off with commas. It can also be at the beginning or end of the sentence.

All of these are fine:

*According to the local team, the part was delivered yesterday.*

*The part was delivered yesterday, according to the local team.*

The "Please be informed" phrase is just throat-clearing, an introduction that is not material to the sentence content.

One more way to consider writing it:

*Please be advised that the part was delivered yesterday (according to the local team).*